# WPF - How to extend an existing toolbar UserControl

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I create a new UserControl for reuse. The UserControl contains a toolbar with several Buttons.

When I use the UserControl, I hope I can add additional Buttons on it but can not modified the orginal ones.

This is easily implemented in WinForm by inheritance. But in WPF, I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to do what you need.

For example, your UserControl could expose ICollection TabButtons property, which is ItemsSource for toolbar. In this case, your toolbar should contain some ItemsControl to host buttons and should be binded to aforementioned TabButtons property.

And TabButton struct should describe all needed information (for example, properties Header, Icon, ToolTip and Command).

Or you could provide appropriate methods: AddToolbarButton(), RemoveToolbarButton(). This methods change TabButtons collection (but the collection itself cann't be accessed from outer realm).